# Using Expression<Func<>> in Where clause with parameters

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following query using linq method syntax

```
IEnumerable<PageElement> elements_test = ObjectContext.PageElements
            .Where(_dateDebutCheck).Where(_dateFinCheck)
            .Where(_activeLanguageCheck(language));

private readonly Expression<Func<PageElement, bool>> _dateDebutCheck = pe => pe.DateDebut.HasValue && pe.DateDebut.Value <= DateTime.Now;
private readonly Expression<Func<PageElement, bool>> _dateFinCheck = pe => !pe.DateFin.HasValue || pe.DateFin.Value > DateTime.Now;

private readonly Expression<Func<PageElement, byte, bool>> _activeLanguageCheck =
        (pe, lang) => pe.PageElementLanguages.Where(y => y.Active).Select(y => y.LanguageId).Contains(lang);
```

The syntax appears to be correct for the first 2 expressions that do not take parameters, how can I invoke the third expression with the language parameter in my Where clause?

Answer (score 7):

Rather than having a lambda with an extra parameter, you can have a method that creates the lambda *capturing* the desired value:

```
private Expression<Func<PageElement, bool>> ActiveLanguageCheck(byte lang) {
    return pe => pe.PageElementLanguages.Where(
                    y => y.Active).Select(y => y.LanguageId).Contains(lang);
}
```

Then just:

```
.Where(ActiveLanguageCheck(language))
```

Comment: Hi Marc, what are the benefits of writting methods like this:  private Expression<Func.....

Comment: @billy_56 that isn't a method - it is an expression tree; the purpose of an expression tree is to allow intent to be either composed (meta-programming) or decomposed (think: "LINQ-to-EF" etc, where intent is translated into SQL). Whether you *need* those things is entirely contextual

Answer (score 1):

The [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb535040%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in LINQ to entities takes an `Expression<Func<TSource, Boolean>>` which is not what you have.

So your question is instead : How to convert `Expression<Func<PageElement, byte, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<PageElement, bool>>`

Here is a simple helper function to do that:

```
public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> ToSimpleFunc<T1, T2, TResult>(Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> f, T2 value)
{
    var invokeExpression = Expression.Invoke(f, f.Parameters[0], Expression.Constant(value));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(invokeExpression, f.Parameters[0]);
}
```

Call it this way:

```
IEnumerable<PageElement> elements_test = ObjectContext.PageElements
        .Where(_dateDebutCheck).Where(_dateFinCheck)
        .Where(ToSimpleFunc(_activeLanguageCheck, language));
```

Comment: Most query providers won't be able to handle the `Invoke` expression and will just fail at runtime.

Comment: Nope, there is no expession to invoke, ToSimpleFunc will be called inline.